# Want to use a method to return a list from foreach and return all items but i get: (collection)

Tags: c#, error-handling

So basically the method is fired when click event occurs on a button to check for a string if it matches  :

```
        lbPlaylist.Items.Add(o.GetFragment(tbTitle.Text));
    }
```

and the code of the method is :

```
    public List<SoundFragment> GetFragment(String p)
    {
        List<SoundFragment> list1 = new List<SoundFragment>();

        //make a list and store every string
        foreach(SoundFragment i in fragments)
        {
            if (i.Title.Contains(p))
            {
                list1.Add(i);
            } 
        }
        //return all the objects from the new list that stores all the string contained in the fragments list
        return list1;
    }
```

Problem is im really returning objects or collection of objects to the listbox and i want to return only the string names that are added . How can i reach them ?

Comment: You're defining your return collection as a collection of fragments. Obviously you will have to add objects to it then.

Comment: Please provide an example object that you expect as result. It is very unclear why your current code does not work for you.

Comment: You're seeing `System.Collection` in your listview because you're adding a `List<SoundFragment>` to the `lbPlaylists.Items`. I guess you want to iterate over all the returned `SoundFragment`s the `GetFragment()` function returns and add them each to the `lbPlaylists.Items`?

Comment: why don't you change the method signature to return a List<string> or a string also would help if we could see what `SoundFragment` looks like..

Comment: yes exacly and im returning a list collection but i want to access the list collection to get from those objects one of their already assigned attributes: string name so i can add them all to the listbox as strings and not as objects . And the method returns a list filled with objects , i only need an instance of those objects but it doesnt allow me to do like a list1.Title or anything like that

Comment: @user5780143 Don't explain what do you want, explain the scenario. Why do you need an instance of `SoundFragment` rather than a `string` to add in `lbPlaylists`? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: okay fixed it guys thanks for the feedback ! i now for example add two songs with some names and when i click a button i call the method which checks with if the object list string instance and if it partially mathes adds to the string list and then finally returns and adds all the members of that string list the listbox. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to Richard's answer, your **main problem** is that line:

```
lbPlaylist.Items.Add(o.GetFragment(tbTitle.Text));
```

Here you add the **whole collection as one item** to the `ListBox`. You have to use

```
lbPlaylist.Items.AddRange(o.GetFragment(tbTitile.Text).ToArray());
```

to add *each object as a single item*.

The `ListBox` will then use the `ToString()` method of the objects in your collection to display a text for each object. If your `SoundFragment` implements a appropriate `ToString()` method for your needs, all works fine. Otherwise you have to modify your `GetFragment` method to somethink like Richard suggested.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to return only the object names in a list of strings, try this

```
public List<string> GetFragment(String p)
{
    List<SoundFragment> list1 = new List<SoundFragment>();
    List<string> result = new List<string>();

    //make a list and store every string
    foreach(SoundFragment i in list1)
    {
        if (i.Title.Contains(p))
        {
            result.Add(i.Title);
        } 
    }
    //return all the objects from the new list that stores all the string contained in the fragments list
    return result ;
}
```

Comment: Why are you iterating over an empty list `list1`?

Comment: already tried that but creating a new list doesn't work since the foreach iterates through SoundFragment which is a list ob objects and not strings

Comment: the list is not empty, i dont understand how to access an instance of an objects in a list that is called in from a class basically :D

Comment: You can extract only the Title of the SoundFragment object, Title is an string and you can add all of them in a new list that you will return